# How to retrieve non-standard nodes from RSS feed

Tags: xml, ruby, parsing, rss

I use the [Simple RSS](http://simple-rss.rubyforge.org/) parser for my project.

It works nicely but I have nodes like this:

```
<dc:creator>viroos</dc:creator>
```

I have no idea how to get nodes like these.

Comment: That node has a namespace, so you have to access them using the namespace and tag. As mentioned by @segy, Nokogiri is a good tool for this. The "Namespaces" section of the "[Searching an HTML / XML Document](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html)" documentation covers this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) instead. It should give you the flexibility you want.

Alternatively based on a quick skim of the simple-rss code, the node might be available as `dc_creator`.